# Node adding braces to request.body parameter

Tags: node.js

When I pass data to my node application, req.body gets garbled. My client call:

```
$.post('/posts/#{post._id}/post', {seen_posts: seen_posts}, function(data, status) {

}
```

My controller function:

```
exports.item_posts_get = function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("SEEN POSTS");
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.body.seen_posts);
}
```

Console:

```
SEEN POSTS
[Object: null prototype] {
  'seen_posts[]': [ '5f6ac9fdae396910b32011c4', '5f6ac9fdae396910b32011c4' ]
}
undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

In your jQuery code try `JSON.stringify({seen_posts: seen_posts})` in place of `{seen_posts: seen_posts}`.

In your nodejs express code put these lines shortly after where you say `const app = express()`

```
/* allow handling json and URL-encoded POST document bodies */
const bodyParser = require( 'body-parser' )
app.use( bodyParser.json() )
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded( { extended: true } ) )
/* allow handling cookies */
const cookieParser = require( 'cookie-parser' )
app.use( cookieParser() )
```

This arranges to pass your data from `$.post()` to your server in JSON format, and parse it into `req.body`.  You can troubleshoot it with the Network tab of your browser devtools.